# Wordpress options text format

Tags: options, formatting

Wordpress converts my theme options text with smart quotes.

I know that to remove problem from posts etc:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');

remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wptexturize');

remove_filter('comment_text', 'wptexturize');
```

But how to remove this effects when saving into Wordpress options api?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress does not automatically texturize [options](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API). If you are using [add_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option), [update_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option), and/or [get_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) then it should "just work".

Example:

```
//Add an option to the database
update_option('my_test_option','This is an option. Isn\'t it "special"?');

//Returns string: This is an option. Isn't it "special"?
echo get_option('my_test_option');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to replace the smart quotes (following is based on code from [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpuntexturize/)), in `functions.php`:

```
function wpse89095_untexturize( $text ) {
    $char_codes   = array( '&#8216;', '&#8217;', '&#8220;', '&#8221;', '&#8242;', '&#8243;' );
    $replacements = array( "'", "'", '"', '"', "'", '"' );
    return str_replace( $char_codes, $replacements, $text );
}
```

Then filter your option before it's saved to the database, in `functions.php`:

```
function wpse89095_untexturize_option( $newvalue, $oldvalue ){
    $newvalue = wpse89095_untexturize( $newvalue );
    return $newvalue;
}
add_filter( 'pre_update_option_{OPTION}', 'wpse89095_untexturize_option', 10, 2 );
```

NB: replace `{OPTION}` with the name of the option you'd like to filter.